# How to set http or https based on window.location.protocol

Tags: api, dart, flutter-web, window.location

I am working on a flutter web application.I want to prevent the CORS error whether my API Endpoint runs on https:// or http:// How can I modify my EndPoint Class below to set http or https based on the current window.location.protocol?
Here is my service class:

```js
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart';

class ApiEndPoint {
  Location currentLocation = window.location;
  static
  const host = 'api.xyz.com';
  static
  const http = 'http://';
  static
  const https = 'https://';
  static String baseUrl = "";
  // get base {
  //   if (currentLocation.protocol == 'https') {
  //     return baseUrl = "$https$host/api";
  //   } else if (currentLocation.protocol == 'http') {
  //     return baseUrl = "$http$host/api";
  //   }
  // }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem:

1. If `currentLocation.host != apihost` (for instance `currentLocation` could be `https://app.xyz.com`) you'll have to allow CORS on your API host anyways. Why then still support unsecure `http://` protocol for your API. It's no problem to access `https://` resources from an unsecured website. Just always use `https://api.xyz.com` and allow CORS origins `http://app.xyz.com` and `https://app.xyz.com`
2. If `currentLocation.host == apihost` just ditch the `protocol://host` part from your apirequests and just access `/api/...`. The browser (resp. webview) will add the correct protocol and host anyways ...

Other than that, what's wrong with your current approach? It should work. But you could probably simplify it to

```
get base {
  return baseUrl = "${currentLocation.protocol}$host/api"
}
```

and ditch the `const static http` and `const static https` string constants.

I don't have any experience with flutter app architecture, nor do I know the architecture of your app. So I don't know whether it's possible to have multiple instances of that `ApiEndPoint` with different `window.locations`. This will probably lead to a problem with your `static String baseUrl`, as a `static` variable is  shared among all instances of a class. So when you have different `window.location`s at the same time, this will be inconsistent. So maybe you should ditch the `baseUrl` variable alltogether and just do

```
get base {
  return "${currentLocation.protocol}$host/api"
}
```

as this will always have the correct protocol for the location of the current instance.

**EDIT** Regarding your comment:

Of course you cannot access the `base` property in a static way. Ie `ApiEndPoint.base` won't work, because `base` is not a [static property](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods). So in principle you have 2 options (depending on your architecture)

1. Change `base` (and of course also `currentLocation`) to be `static`. Then you can access it vie `ApiEndPoint.base`

   ```
    static Location currentLocation = window.location;
    static get base {
      return "${currentLocation.protocol}$host/api"
    }
   ```
2. Create an instance of your `ApiEndPoint` class, and access the `base` property only via that instance

   ```
    final api = ApiEndPoint();
    ...
    final baseUrl = api.base;
   ```

In any case, you should read about `static` keyword ...

Comment: The problem is with both your implementation and mine while trying to access the base variable from my service class I get an error "Instance member 'base' can't be accessed using static access"
i.e when I try to assign the base as follows final baseUrl = ApiEndPoint.base; to the baseUrl variable. How then can i access this base value?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Okay I will study the use of static keyword